# Redirect to https a rails application reverse proxied with apache using .htaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, redirect, proxy

I am running a simple rails application on port 3000. I have reverse proxied it to apache port 80 with mod_rewrite enabled. When I access via http and https the application works fine. Now I would like to redirect all http request to https. I already have a .htaccess file under public folder of the rails application but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Domain.com points to my domain. Also I don't want my subdomains to be redirected to https. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the OR condition and try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Removing the OR condition isn't helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "isnt helpful"?

Comment: http isn't redirected to https

Comment: This works fine on my server. what exactly happens when you go to http://domain also are there any other directives in the htaccess ?

Comment: No there aren't anyother directives

Answer (score 0):

To check if https is enabled, you can use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the `HTTPS` variable

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Should I replace the content in my .htaccess with this or append it?

Comment: This is just for the redirection to https. If you have other rules in your config, keep them. If you want to strip `www.`, you need additional rules.